# In posts page show only last 2 years posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created a page for posts called Blog, in Reading settings I have selected Blog page as posts page. Now what I want is I want show only last two years posts, not all. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic code for your query.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'       => 'date',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
            'before' => '2 year ago',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();   
    /*
    * Your HTML styles to display the post
    */
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
<?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Also, please refer to the following document for more knowledge about it.

[Query in WP Date](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

Hope its works for you

Thanks